# Deleting or renaming one of two instances of zsh in /etc/shells

Tags: macos, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I installed zsh with Oh-My-Zsh via a GitHub link which handled all the heavy lifting for me like setting up PATHs, setting zsh as default shell and writing loads of functions on `~/.zshrc`(since I was new with terminal at the time I installed it).

I noticed that it runs quite slow at login due to the numerous number of commands in `~/.zshrc`.
(which I plan to rectify by changing my default shell to bash and just calling zsh whenever needed)

But I see 2 instances of zsh in `/etc/shells` (and only one in the advanced settings of my user in the system systems of macOS from where one can change shells using a GUI). Below is the result I get on running `cat /etc/shells`:

```
# List of acceptable shells for chpass(1).
# Ftpd will not allow users to connect who are not using
# one of these shells.

/bin/bash
/bin/csh
/bin/dash
/bin/ksh
/bin/sh
/bin/tcsh
/bin/zsh
/usr/local/bin/zsh
```

Can I safely delete either of these and how? Or give each of them a different command to be called, assuming they are different from each other.

For reference, my default shell is `/usr/local/bin/zsh` but running `zsh` in the terminal gets me to `/bin/zsh` (still with all the settings of `/usr/local/bin/zsh`).

Comment: I wouldn't delete either of them. Just run `chsh -s /bin/bash` to use bash as your main shell, and then `chsh -s /bin/zsh` to switch to zsh. By the way I doubt oh-my-zsh is slowing you down much out of the box.

Comment: `/etc/shells` is a bit of an odd file: it's a record of *which* shells are allowed to be used as login shells. Which shell you get when you run `zsh` is purely a function of your `PATH`, not the contents of `/etc/shells`.